# Python: parsing logs from remote server

Tags: python, bash, ssh, grep, subprocess

I need to process log files from a remote directory and parse their contents. This task can be divided into the following:

1. Run `ssh find` with criteria to determine files to process
2. Get the relevant contents of these files with `zgrep`
3. Process the results from *2* with a python algorithm and store to a local db

Steps *1* and *3* are very fast, so I am looking to improve Step 2.

The files are stored as gz or plaintext and the order in which they are processed is very important. Newer logs need to be processed first to avoid discrepancies with older logs.

To get and filter the log lines, I have tried the following approaches:

1. Download logs to a temp folder and process them as they are downloaded, in parallel. A python process triggers an `scp` command and a parallel thread inspects the temp folder for completed downloads until `scp` is finished. If the file is downloaded run `zgrep`, process and delete the file.
2. Run `ssh remote zgrep "regex" file1 file2 file3`, grab the results and process them.

Method 2 is a more readable and elegant solution, however it is also much slower. Using method 1 I can download and parse 280 files in about 1:30 minutes. Using method 2, it will take closer to 5:00 minutes. One of the main problems with the download-process approach is that the directory can be altered while the script is running, leading to several checks being needed in the code.

To run the shell commands from python I am currently using `subprocess.check_output` and the `multiprocessing` and `threading` modules.

Can you think of a way this algorithm can be improved?

Comment: "70 million lines" doesn't sound like much. Have you tried to run `zgrep` on the remote host as as [@devnull suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23632016/4279) or `scp` files to the local machine and then run `zgrep` ? The performance bottleneck might be a disk I/O on the remote machine, network bandwidth between the localhost and the `remote`, CPU on the localhost. It is hard to tell from your description. To find out, measure: how long `zgrep "regex" file*`  takes for local (relative to zgrep) files from cache, how long `zcat file* >/dev/null` takes, `ssh remote zcat file* >/dev/null`.

Comment: Unrelated: you could try [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/) instead of running `ssh` commands

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian I edited the description with some more info

Comment: Are you sure both methods produce the same result and the time measurements are accurate? Why is `ssh remote zgrep` so slow compared to `scp + (local)zgrep`?

Comment: Yes, the results are the same and I ran both a few times, then took the average. With the scp command, I grep each file as it finishes downloading, so there are several smaller grep operations. With the other one, I grep the whole thing in one go. Can this affect performance? It might be the case that the remote machine is simply much slower.

Comment: Have you tried to run `zgrep 'regex' files* >/dev/null` on both machines several times for the same set of files to confirm that the remote machine is slower and it is not some error in your code?

Comment: What happens if you mount the remote directory (e.g., using sshfs) and run zgrep locally?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian sorry for the late response. Unfortunately I don't have enough priviledges to mount a drive. There are several constraints not allowing me to try different approaches, so I think I'll stick to the download-process solution for now.

Comment: as far as I understand, [you don't need special permissions if sshfs is already installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately it's not installed :(